# Stacking boxes left to right from the bottom with CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to stack boxes from left to right (bottom up) and to do this as simple as possible (either purely CSS or with JS, whichever is simpler). See below for illustration.

When there's only **one non-full row**:

```
┌─────────────────────────┐
│                         │
│                         │
│       1  2  3  4        │
│                         │
│                         │
└─────────────────────────┘
```

**One fully-filled row:**

```
┌─────────────────────────┐
│                         │
│                         │
│   1  2  3  4  5  6  7   │
│                         │
│                         │
└─────────────────────────┘
```

**More than one row:**

```
┌─────────────────────────┐
│                         │
│                         │
│   8  9  10              │
│   1  2  3  4  5  6  7   │
│                         │
└─────────────────────────┘
```

**Many rows:**

```
┌─────────────────────────┐
│                         │
│                         │
│   15 16 17              │
│   8  9  10 11 12 13 14  │
│   1  2  3  4  5  6  7   │
└─────────────────────────┘
```

It's hard to describe without showing the diagrams. What would be the simplest way of implementing this? What's the HTML5 way?

**EDIT:**

Added this fiddle to show my progress thus far: http://jsfiddle.net/12Lk7h45/

I need the bottom row to be fully filled, while the top row should be partially filled. Also, how do I set a rule such that when there are less elements than a full row, it should all be horizontally centered?

If you didn't want to click into the fiddle, here is what I wrote down:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box"><div class="label">1</div></div>
    <div class="box"><div class="label">2</div></div>
    <div class="box"><div class="label">3</div></div>
    <div class="box"><div class="label">4</div></div>
    <div class="box"><div class="label">5</div></div>
    <div class="box"><div class="label">6</div></div>
    <div class="box"><div class="label">7</div></div>
    <div class="box"><div class="label">8</div></div>
    <div class="box"><div class="label">9</div></div>
    <div class="box"><div class="label">10</div></div>
    <div class="box"><div class="label">11</div></div>
    <div class="box"><div class="label">12</div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%
}

.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.label {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.box:nth-child(5n+1) {
    background-color: green;
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Maybe make a fiddle and we can help you better.

Comment: I agree with the above comment. If you want us to help you then you need to give us something to work with, `source` not images. It would be a good idea to display your attempt of doing this too.

Comment: @jungy I don't know where to start, so unfortunately I haven't gotten much farther than this: http://jsfiddle.net/12Lk7h45/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way might be to use flexbox.

Here I did it with on Code Pen. You can use a polyfill if you have compatibility issues with flex box

http://codepen.io/cjthedizzy/pen/wBpadE

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 flex-flow:  row-reverse wrap-reverse; //THIS CHANGES THE FLOW TO REVERSE
 -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 width:500px;
 background:#000;
 }
```

Polyfill
http://flexiejs.com/

Comment: I like this answer more than the other one, it seems more elegant since it doesn't rely on rotating stuff.

Comment: I also checked caniuse and the only browser flexbox doesnt work on is opera mini and of course old versions of IE

Answer (score 3):

You can used my code, still not good but working not bad 
[my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xq566v58/1/)   (just use CSS)

```
<div style="" id="content">
    <div style="height: 50%; width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: 0px;">               
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>11</li>
            <li>12</li>
            <li>13</li>
            <li>14</li>
            <li>15</li>
            <li>16</li>
            <li>17</li>
            <li>18</li>
            <li>19</li>
            <li>20</li>
         </ul>
       </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content{
width: 200px; 
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(237, 237, 237); 
height: 200px;
position: relative;
}
#content li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 5px;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
ul{
margin: 0px; 
list-style: outside none none;
width: 100%; 
transform: rotate(180deg); 
padding: 0px 20px; 
float: left;
bottom: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: That's really interesting, so you just line it up right-to-left, rotate the whole container and then rotate the labels?